# passing a vector parameter empty

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, parameter-passing, stdvector

I have been using this class :

```cpp
class DogTrainer 
{
    public:
        DogTrainer(int identity,const std::string& nom, const std::vector<Dog*> dogz) :    
         idD(identity),
         name(nom),
         trainees(dogz)
    { };

        ~DogTrainer();

    private:
        int idD;
        string name;
        std::vector<Dog*> trainees;
};
```

but sometimes when I want to instantiate a new object, I don't need to pass a "trainees"  parameter, so I want to have the possiblity to do this

```cpp
DogTrainer* Trainer=new DogTrainer(my_id, my_name);
```

therefore I tried to change in my DogTrainer constructor

```cpp
DogTrainer(int identity,const std::string& nom, const std::vector<Dog*> dogz="") :
    idD(identity), 
    name(nom), 
    trainees(dogz)
{ };
```

but it didn't work so any help please !

Comment: Why a string literal? It's not a std::string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your constructor as:

```
DogTrainer(int identity,const std::string& nom,
           const std::vector<Dog*> dogz = std::vector<Dog*>());
```

`""` is a `const char*`, and a `std::vector` is not constructible from that.

Incidentally, there's not much point in `dogz` being a `const std::vector<Dog*>`.  Either make it non-`const` or make it a `const` reference.

Comment: What is the use of this default parameter. This is already the default value of the vector.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: if you don't specify a default, the argument is not optional, and the OP is trying to get an optional parameter to work.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: In this particular case, you're right.  The `vector` member will be initialized appropriately anyway.  But it seems that the poster is confused about default arguments in general, so I gave a general answer.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work because you are trying to assign empty string to a `vector`. Just overload the constructor omitting the last parameter.

```
DogTrainer(int identity,const std::string& nom, const std::vector<Dog*> dogz)
    :idD(identity), name(nom), trainees(dogz) {
};

DogTrainer(int identity,const std::string& nom):idD(identity), name(nom) {
};
```

This will virtually be the same from user perspective to what you want to achieve.

Comment: so I've done two constructors but the compiler generated an ambiguity error between two candidates for the same function ! so what should i do ??

Comment: @Glolita maybe you did, but you did not remove the default value in the first one, did you? In my solution I meant that no default value should be given.